# Pass state back to parent AND pass other props from parent to child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know how to pass the state from child to parent. And I know how to pass props from parent to child.

However, the obvious way for doing both at the same time doesn't seem to work as I expected. Please see an example below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child = (props, { other }) => {
  // This is what I'd like to achieve but it ignores the {other} prop and doesn't received it from parent

  // const Child = ({ other }) => { // Works, but the sending of props from child to parent stops working
  // const Child = (props) => { // Works too but obviously the 'other' prop is not passed anymore
  return (
    <>
      Child
      <button onClick={() => props.setValue("New stuff")}>Click!</button>
      <p>{other}</p>
    </>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("Default value");

  return (
    <>
      Parent <Child setValue={setValue} other={"Something else"} />
      <p>{value}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

I tried passing both as `{props, other}`, `(props, other)`, `({props, {other}})` but nothing worked.

Here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-dawn-4vnir?file=/src/Parent.js) to Codesandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `other` from `props`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      Child
      <button onClick={() => props.setValue("New stuff")}>Click!</button>
      <p>{props.other}</p>
    </>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("Default value");

  return (
    <>
      Parent <Child setValue={setValue} other={"Something else"} />
      <p>{value}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `const Child = ({other, ...props }) => {`

CodeSandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-gagarin-3cgto

Answer (score 0):

The `props` parameter in this case actually contains both of the `setValue` and `other` props.

The destructuring syntax is also helpful for legibility here.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child = (props) => {
  // destructure both setValue and other out of props
  const {setValue, other} = props
  return (
    <>
      Child
      <button onClick={() => setValue("New stuff")}>Click!</button>
      <p>{other}</p>
    </>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("Default value");

  return (
    <>
      Parent <Child setValue={setValue} other={"Something else"} />
      <p>{value}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Comment: Thank you! Your suggested solution is working great too, but I had to choose one and I went with @2pichar answer, since I can avoid writing an extra line.